# Are all closed sets regions?

Tags: general-topology

My lectures notes on complex analysis define a **region** like this:

> Suppose that $S \subseteq \mathbb{C}$. The set $S$ is a **region** if it is an open set together with none, some, or all of its boundary points.

Are all closed sets regions? I *believe* this is equivalent to asking: for every closed set $S$, is it true that there exists some open set $T$ such that $T \subseteq S$? I can't find a counterexample.

As a positive example, I believe the null set is a region: take $\emptyset \text{ (open)} \subseteq \emptyset \text{ (closed)}$.

Comment: $S=\Bbb R{}{}$?

Comment: Every closed set contains the empty set, which is an open set.

Comment: @AnginaSeng $\mathbb{R}$ is clopen, so take $\mathbb{R} \text{ (open)} \subseteq \mathbb{R} \text{ (closed)}$

Comment: The reals are *not* open in the complex numbers.

Comment: @GerryMyerson I didn't realise, but we can take $\emptyset \subseteq \mathbb{R}$ anyway.

Comment: " I believe this is equivalent to asking..." but it isn't. It's equivalent to asking whether for every closed set $S$ there is an open set $T$ whose *closure* is $S$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your reformulation is not correct. Since $\emptyset$ is open, every set $X$ is a region according to your reformulation: $\emptyset\subseteq X$.

According to the initial definition, every 1-dimensional infinite set(say, an interval) is not a region.

Comment: Can we say all unbounded closed sets are not regions?

Comment: An infinite line is unbounded and has no interior, so it is not a region.

Comment: I believe $\{ z \in \mathbb{C} : |\operatorname{Im}(z)| \leq 1 \}$ is closed. Is this an example of a 2-dimensional set that is not a region? Can I go so far as to say that *every* 2-dimensional set in $\mathbb{C}$ *except* for $\mathbb{C}$ is not a region?

Comment: No, this is a region: it is the open set $\{z\in \Bbb C| |Im(z)|<1\}$ together with its boundary.

Comment: $\emptyset$ has no boundary points, so taking that as the "core" we do not get any non-empty $X$.

Comment: @HennoBrandsma: Did I say that we get nonempty regions this way? What is your comment for?

Answer (score 0):

A set $A$ is a region iff $$A \subseteq \overline{\operatorname{int}(A)}$$

$\Bbb R \subseteq \Bbb C$ is a closed set that is not a region (its interior is empty) and also $\{z\mid \text{Re}(z) > 0\} \cup \Bbb R$ does have an non-trivial interior, but points of $\Bbb R$ that are $<0$ aren't boundary points of the interior, which is the first set in the union.

But of course $\Bbb C$ and $\Bbb C\setminus \{0\}$ and many other unbounded sets *are* "regions". In my analysis course a region had to be open non-empty and connected in $\Bbb C$. Then we can talk about derivatives everywhere etc.